# SQL query not displaying the first result?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to dynamically create a navigation menu in my php page.

I have a query to create a list of the active pages but for some reason the first result never shows

```
$menu = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM myTable WHERE active_page='y' ORDER BY menu_order");
$menulist = mysql_fetch_array($menu);

  while($menulist = mysql_fetch_array($menu))
  {
  $themenu = $themenu . "<li><a href='#'>" . $menulist['link'] . "</a></li>";
  }

  $echo $themenu;
```

returns

item 2
item 3
item 4
...

Any ideas why this might be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove

```
$menulist = mysql_fetch_array($menu);
```

This extraneous call is pulling the first record, but you're not doing anything with it as you are in your where loop.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't display the first item because you are fetching twice before displaying anything...

```
$menu = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM myTable WHERE active_page='y' ORDER BY menu_order");

  while($menulist = mysql_fetch_array($menu))
  {
  $themenu = $themenu . "<li><a href='#'>" . $menulist['link'] . "</a></li>";
  }

  $echo $themenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should drop

```
$menulist = mysql_fetch_array($menu);
```

This moves the cursor one step forward and efficently skips the first row.

You should also drop the `$` before your `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

It's skipping the 1st element because you are calling `mysql_fetch_array($menu)` before the `while` loop.