# First record from database is not displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Trying to work on a clients site and I am having a bit of difficulty.  When I have no entries in the database, it catches at `if(!row)` and displays the message.  This part works fine.  My issue is when I have entries in the db, they do not display.  I know the while loop works because I have several pages running a similar loop.  In fact, this loop was copied from another page that displays this entry's information on a public page.

I know this site is mainly for questions, but I think I just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at my code(I've been coding for over 12 hours and I'm a bit tired).  A lot of the code below is from a previous web designer and if it were up to me, I would just rewrite the entire site because the code is "out of date", but the client just wants me to improve on it.  Any help would be greatly apprecieated.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (!$row) {
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="ffffff" colspan="3"><font face="arial,helvetica" size="2" color="000000">There are no entries at this time, check back later.</font></td></tr>';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<tr>
                    <td bgcolor="ffffff"><font face="arial,helvetica" size="2" color="000000">$date - $row["theme"]</font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="ffffff" align="center">
                    <form action="dsp_modifyposition.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="specialID" value="$row["specialID"]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="theme" value="$row["theme"]">
                        <input type="submit" value="  Modify  ">
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="ffffff" align="center">
                    <form action="act_deleteposition.php" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this event: $date \')">
                        <input type="hidden" name="specialID" value="$row["specialID"]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="theme" value="$row["theme"]">
                        <input type="submit" value="  Delete  ">
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You do understand that `$row` is initialized after your `if` is performed, don't you?

Comment: "I left them out because I know for a fact they are correct." --- if they are correct - then your code works fine

Comment: Hold on one moment, going back and checking again

Comment: if there is only one element in the resultset, the second mysql_fetch returns false an you print nothing

Comment: You're attempting to echo variables (`$row["theme"]`) within a `'` block. That won't work.

Comment: Just noticed that, must have done that in haste.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query not displaying the first result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492344/sql-query-not-displaying-the-first-result) (Whoot! Score! The magic of a good title and related questions!)

Comment: I had originally posted it with a different title because I thought it wasn't displaying any of the information.  I just happened to only have one value in the db at the time.  If I had more than one I would most likely have caught the other post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call mysql_fetch_array for the first time, the mysql result pointer is moved to the next row. Because nothing is done with this row, this first row does not get displayed. What you want is `mysql_num_rows` to check how many rows are in the resultset. As a side-note, I would suggest using `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you're not using the numeric indices.

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo '...';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '...';
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){ ... } else { }`

Comment: This fixed my issue.  Now to go back to all of the other scripts and fix them.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Change your first lines to this:

```
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($result)

if (!$cnt) {
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="ffffff" colspan="3"><font face="arial,helvetica" size="2" color="000000">There are no entries at this time, check back later.</font></td></tr>';
} else {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if() statement seems flawed.  The statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

will fetch a row and move the pointer in $result to the next row, so your while will start at the second row.  If your query returns only one row, you're effectively calling mysql_fetch_array() twice and skipping over the data returned.

You should find some other way of checking if you have results (possibly with mysql_num_rows()).

Comment: Thank you, just realized that all of my scripts are this way and that I need to fix them.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.