# First result While loop hidden

Tags: php, html, database, while-loop

I have the common newbie problem of the first hidden While loop result. I've searched and, even when I know there are [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923983/first-record-from-database-is-not-displayed) available, I have an example in which `mysql_fetch_assoc`is not being used, and it does show all results on Database. I am tring to show my results as the example shown here, but even when I think is similarry built, my document hides first result.

Example in which all resuts are shown:

```
$numeroRegistros = mysql_num_rows($parametroConsulta);

        if($numeroRegistros == 0){
            echo "No hay datos en la Agenda";
        }
        else{
            while($registro = mysql_fetch_array($parametroConsulta)){
                echo "<li><strong>".$registro['nombre']."</strong> : ".$registro['movil']." || <a href='borrar.php?id=".$registro['id_contactos']."'>Borrar</a>|| <a href='editar.php?id=".$registro['id_contactos']."'>Editar</a> </li>";
            }
        }
```

My example hiding first result:

```
        if(consultaNumRegistros($consulta) == 0){
        echo '<td colspan="3" class="footerRow">No hay turnos registrados en el sistema.</td>';
        }
        else{
            $tu_id = $registroBbdd['tu_id'];            
            $tu_name = $registroBbdd['tu_name'];
            ?>
    <tbody>
            <?php
                while($registroBbdd = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

                    echo '<tr>
                        <td><span class="tableContentRow">'.$registroBbdd['tu_name'].'</span></td>
                        </tr>';
                }
            }?></tbody>
```

I have learned that mysql_fetch_array uses one counter when being called so it passes to the next one, but why are all results shown on the first one, and not on the second one, where it hides the first of them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but please can you explain a bit more clearly? What hides again? Also you are declaring `$registroBbdd` inside the while block but it's also being used in the `else` block of `if` which is wrong (unless you have declare it up somewhere too)

Comment: Both examples are biult te same, as far as I think. First one shows all results on table. Secnd one hides first result, showing all results on table except the first one. Equal methods are being used. Why does second one not show first result?

Comment: You mean from the rows you fetch, you want to hide only the first result?

Comment: Your code seems to be absolutely fine

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, no, I want to show all  results. Now it  is hiding first one for some reason I do not know yet.

Comment: In your else block: `else{
            $tu_id = $registroBbdd['tu_id'];  //remove this line           
            $tu_name = $registroBbdd['tu_name']; //and this line`

Comment: @Fazovsky What do you mean? That's normal. That line means to fetch a result set from `$select` as an array and put it into `$registroBbdd`

Comment: Done @ICanHasCheezburger, in deed that variable was not needed here but this does not seem to be the reason of the hide, as it keeps hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand very well your problem, but maybe you should use reset($array) to resetting array pointers, and then use again

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't access your results somewhere before the `while` loop?

Does your `consultaNumRegistros` method use it by any chance?

Comment: Hi, thank you. consultaNumRegistros shows the total amount of found matches before the while, but I've deleted it from there and that does not seem to be the problem, as it keeps hiding first result. Hope I understood your question

Comment: I'm not PHP expert, but it needs to be case, that you are accessing result and some 'magical php pointer' gets moved one position further.  There is no other explanation. Double check your code for that.

Comment: I guess thats the only solution, as I am not able to see the reason for starting on counter 1. Thank you.